# Reading XML DOCTYPE info with Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to parse a version of an XML file as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE twReport [ 
<!ELEMENT twReport (twHead?, (twWarn | twDebug | twInfo)*, twBody, twSum?, 
               twDebug*, twFoot?, twClientInfo?)> 
<!ATTLIST twReport version CDATA "10,4"> <----- VERSION INFO HERE
```

I use xml.dom.minidom for parsing XML file, and I need to parse the version of the XML file written in embedded DTD.

- Can I use xml.dom.minidom for this purpose?
- Is there any python XML parser for that purposes?

Comment: What does "easy" mean?  Using the various xml parsers in Python seems pretty easy.  What more could you want?

Comment: I wanted to get the easier solution - something like using xml.dom.minidom or similar, not using Python's SAX, or other 3rd party library.

Comment: The question says "I want to use ... xml.dom.minidom".  You comment says  "using xml.dom.minidom".   Clearly, you think that's easier.    What's the question?

Comment: I use xml.dom.minidom for parsing XML file, and I need to parse the version of the XML file written in embedded DTD. So, what I wanted to know was

* Can I use xml.dom.minidom for this purpose?
* Is there any python XML parser for that purposes?

I guess the answer to the first question is 'no', and I also see the answer to the second question is 'yes'. But the best solution might be just read and parse the XML using regular expression.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify it.  Adding comments to a question you own makes it hard for others to follow.  Please clarify your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [xmlproc](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/software/xmlproc/)'s [DTD api](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/software/xmlproc/dtd-api-doco.html)?

Here's a random snippet of code I wrote years and years ago to do some work with DTDs from Python, which might give you an idea of what it's like to work with this library:

```
from xml.parsers.xmlproc import dtdparser

attr_separator = '_'
child_separator = '_'

dtd = dtdparser.load_dtd('schedule.dtd')

for name, element in dtd.elems.items():
    for attr in element.attrlist:
        output = '%s%s%s = ' % (name, attr_separator, attr)
        print output
    for child in element.get_valid_elements(element.get_start_state()):
        output = '%s%s%s = ' % (name, child_separator, child)
        print output
```

(FYI, this was the first result when [searching for "python dtd parser"](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+dtd+parser))

Comment: It seems pretty good, but the DTD information that has the version number is a part of the XML file.

Comment: What information do you actually need out of this file?  Is it just the version information from the embedded DTD?  If so, why don't you just pull it out with a regular expression?

Comment: And I guess I should point out that the `xmlproc` parsers provide a `get_dtd` method that will give you access to the DTD of a parsed XML file.  Which may or may not be what you're looking for.  This is all explained in the docs that I linked to.

Comment: > why don't you just pull it out with a regular expression?
That's actually what I did for getting the job done, but I wanted to know if there are some functions for doing it.

Thanks, and it was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Because both of the the standard library XML libraries (`xml.dom.minidom` and `xml.etree`) use the same parser (`xml.parsers.expat`) you are limited in the "quality" of XML data you are able to successfully parse.

You're better off using the tried-and-true 3rd party modules out there like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` that are not only more resilient to errors, but will also give you exactly what you are looking for with little trouble.